# creat-next-app creates with typescritpt. I want it to be in js files

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create next app with below command but it creates with typescript not with js. **How to create with JS?**

```
npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss project-name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js example [you're reffering to](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) is only written in TypeScript. You have 2 options on what to do:

1. Remove typescript from the generated project
2. Use the [example with tailwind + emotion.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss-emotion) and remove the emotion.js (probably the easier one of the two). You can generate the before referenced project with this command: `npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss-emotion project-name`

Answer (score 0):

recently I have faced the same problem, that I want to install next with javascript only and finally, I got a solution for this, you have to use the below command

npx create-next-app (app name) --js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).